# Do I leave the 0 vector in my transition matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

The $2\times 2$ matrices of the form:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

where the entries $a_{ij}$ are all real numbers, form a subspace of the vector space $M_{2\times 2}$.

Both B_1 =
{ [1 1]  [1 1]  [1 0] } and
             [1 0]  [0 0]  [0 0]

B_2=
{ [1 2]  [1 0]  [0 0]
[3 0]  [1 0]  [2 0]
are bases for the subspace.
Find the transition matrix P_B1 --->P_B2

My question lies with the 0 vector.
Do I include that in my transition?  Like this:
[1 1 1 0  1 2 3 0]
[1 1 0 0  1 0 1 0]
[1 0 0 0  0 0 2 0]

To get an answer of:
 [0 0  2 0]
[1 0 -1 0]
[0 2  2 0]

OR do I leave it out like this:
[1 1 1   1 2 3]
[1 1 0   1 0 1]
[1 0 0   0 0 2]

To get an answer of:
[0 0  2]
[1 0 -1]
[0 2  2]

Comment: @Amzoti - I couldn't see how to write Matrices in Mathjax.  I tried but it didn't work.  Basically I need to know if I keep that 0 vector in my transition matrix.  If I do then I have a problem when I then multiply by the coordinate vector to get  a 3x1 coordinate vector. (Does that make sense?)

Comment: While a transition matrix, which necessarily is invertible by virtue of converting from coordinates of one basis to another, cannot have a "zero vector" in the sense of zero rows or zero columns, there can be zero entries.  E.g. the transition matrix that converts from a basis to itself is the identity matrix, and that certainly has zero entries (at least for $n\gt 1$).

Comment: Thank you @hardmath.  So I need to leave that zero out of my matrix correct?  B/C it creates a column of zeros.  I also added a picture of the problem to help.

Comment: A correct procedure for constructing a transition matrix will not produce a column of zeros, so there is actually a bigger step of understanding involved than just leaving out that column.  I started to reformat the first matrix or so using MathJax, but your edit to add the picture interrupted that.  Give me a few minutes and I'll show you how a matrix can be marked up.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with that formatting.  I'm brand new to posting on here so that helps!  Now in your last comment to me @hardmath, you said that there is a "bigger step of understanding involved than just leaving out that column."  Could you please explain what I should know about this?  Thank you!

Comment: First let's note that zero vectors do not appear in an ordered basis (which is just a basis where the elements are assigned a specific order/sequence).  To determine the transition matrix $T$ that converts from coordinates with respect to ordered basis $B_1$ to coordinates with respect to ordered basis $B_2$ we need to know how each vector in $B_1$ can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $B_2$.  The coefficients of this linear combination then form the column of $T$ corresponding to the vector in $B_1$ we are "translating".

Comment: Since you have two (ordered) bases of size three, $T$ will be a $3\times 3$ matrix, the "transition matrix" that translates from $B_1$-coordinates to $B_2$-coordinates.

Comment: So do I need to do a calculation of linear combination first?  I'm confused as far as how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this problem, you can proceed by inspection. You're trying to find the change-of-basis matrix from $B_1$ to $B_2$, so what you really need to do is write each element of $B_1$ as a linear combination of the elements of $B_2$.

Suppose $B_1$ has elements $b_{1,1}, b_{1,2}, b_{1,3}$ and $B_2$ has elements $b_{2,1}, b_{2,2}, b_{2,3}$ (in the precise order they appear in the question statement).

Then you can trivially check:

$b_{1,1} = \frac{1}{2}(b_{2,1}-b_{2,3})+\frac{1}{2}b_{2,2}$

$b_{1,3} = b_{2,2}-\frac{1}{2}b_{2,3}$

Can you figure out $b_{1,2}$ by inspection? The matrix you're looking for will simply be the coordinate vectors $[b_{1,i}]_{B_2}$ as columns.

Comment: So is my written answer correct?  I think I wrote my matrix on the green picture as the coordinate vectors as columns.

Comment: I don't understand the statement "Then you can trivally check:
b1,1 = 1/2....
b1,3 = b2,2....
Where does the 1/2 come from?
In my green picture above, is that matrix that I set up the way that I need to find the linear combination if the elements of B2?
I know I have them backwards in that pic...B2 needs to be on the left and B1 on the right.  But is that the idea?
If it is, then I do not get the same first column you mention in your comment.  I get (1/2, -1/2, 1/2)T.